# Zend file upload does not allow or know svg extension

Tags: php, image, zend-framework, svg

I want to offer the option to upload an image with .svg extension so it is scalable on a pdf print from and within the application. 
I have changed the Validator in the form to this (even tried case sensitive):

```
->addValidator('Extension', false, 'jpg,png,gif,jpeg,svg,SVG')
```

But I get "error: Unknown file format".

Why is this error and how can I allow for files with .svg extension to upload?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should consider to use a IsImage validation:

```
$element->addValidator('IsImage', false);
```

This validates all image formats, including SVG format.

http://framework.zend.com/manual/1.12/en/zend.file.transfer.validators.html#zend.file.transfer.validators.isimage

---

This validator is based on the MimeType validator, so you can also validate directly with MimeType:

```
$element->addValidator('MimeType', false, 'image');
```

or specific type:

```
$element->addValidator('MimeType', false, array('image/gif', 'image/jpeg');
```

http://framework.zend.com/manual/1.12/en/zend.file.transfer.validators.html#zend.file.transfer.validators.mimetype